# Dataset collapsing/reducing

Tags: dataset, associations, gathering

I have a dataset `ds` with 3 columns named A, B, C. Columns A and B have repeated values. How can I obtain another dataset that contains a list of the values in C for each of the unique combinations of A and B?

For example,

```
ds = Dataset[
    {<| "A" -> 2, "B" -> 3, "C" -> 100 |>,
     <| "A" -> 2, "B" -> 4, "C" -> 200 |>,
     <| "A" -> 2, "B" -> 3, "C" -> 300 |>}]
```

I want to get

```
Dataset[
 {<| "A" -> 2, "B" -> 3, "Clist" -> {100, 300} |>,
  <| "A" -> 2, "B" -> 4, "Clist" -> {200} |>}]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: closely related: [Average dataset with many repetitions?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104089/5478)

Comment: and [Enabling JoinAcross to merge non-joined keys](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/108218/5478)

Comment: and a slightly related: [Reshaping associations, generalization of GroupBy](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107399/5478)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get a list of *C* values for each *A*/*B* combination:

```
ds[GroupBy[{#A, #B}&] /* Values
, <| "A" -> Query[First, "A"]
   , "B" -> Query[First, "B"]
   , "CList" -> Query[All, "C"]
   |>
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This is not as succinct as SQL's *GROUP BY* operator, but it does allow us to easily perform multiple aggregations if desired:

```
ds[GroupBy[{#A, #B}&] /* Values
, <| "A" -> Query[First, "A"]
   , "B" -> Query[First, "B"]
   , "CList" -> Query[All, "C"]
   , "CMean" -> Query[Mean, "C"]
   , "CMin" -> Query[Min, "C"]
   , "CMax" -> Query[Max, "C"]
   |>
]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

Comment: I really think you should write a tutorial on `Dataset[]` at some point... I keep picking up new stuff from your answers on this topic. :)

Answer (score 8):

Failed to find a duplicate:

```
by = {"A", "B"};

Values @ GroupBy[ds, Query[by], MapAt[First, List /@ by] @* Merge[Identity]]
```

[image]

or:

```
ds // GroupBy[Query[{"A", "B"}] -> (#C &)] // KeyValueMap[<|#, "Clist" -> #2|> &]

ds // GroupBy[Query[{"A", "B"}]] //  KeyValueMap[<|#, "Clist" -> #2[[;; , "C"]]|> &]
```

Comment: Thanks for an accept but it is always good to hold on a day or two. Let's not discourage others.

Comment: awesome, what if I wanted to "reduce" the resulting dataset by computing say the mean of the list instead?

Comment: @amrods Then take a look at the first topic linked in comments. It seems to be exactly that.`Merge[Mean]` is nice in a way that it will automatically reduce `A` and `B` lists to the repeating element. Here we have a more general case where I have to use `First` manually.

Comment: Thanks. I really thought there would be a cleaner way of achieving this, since I think is a fairly common operation on a dataset.

Answer (score 5):

You may use `GroupBy` and `Merge`.

```
ds[GroupBy[{#"A", #"B"} &] /* Values, 
 Merge[Identity] /* Query[{"A" -> First, "B" -> First}]]
```

[image]

Hope this helps