# Aggregate function problem

Tags: dataset, associations, query

I use a function to do something similar to a SQL sum.  I've asked about simplifying it in [another post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149293/125).  I'm still using this function and it works well for aggregates like `Total` or `Mean`.  It doesn't work for `Count` though. The function is:

```
mySum[x_, keys1_, keys2_, values_] := Module[{a1, a2, a3, a4, a5},
  a1 = Dataset[x];
  a2 = a1[GroupBy[keys1], Total, values];
  a3 = Normal[Values[a2]];
  a4 = Normal[Keys[a2]];
  a5 = AssociationThread[keys2 -> #] & /@ a4;
  MapThread[Join, {a5, a3}]
];
```

I tried `Count` directly in a `Dataset`, where it also failed. I really don't know what to try next. The `Dataset` example in Help gets into other sorts of details and I couldn't see anything applicable to this situation.

The only other thing I could think of, which I haven't tried, is using `Total` and `Mean`, joining the results and calculating the count.  That seems pretty awkward.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: any examples to work with?

Comment: using the example `a2` from your other question, does the following modification of WReach's answer give what you need: `a2[GroupBy[KeyTake[{"L1", "L2"}] -> KeyTake[{"V1", "V2"}]] /* 
  KeyValueMap[Join], Merge[Total@*Counts]]` ?

Comment: maybe  `Length`, or `Total@*Unitize` or `Total@*Counts` instead of `Count`?

Answer (score 2):

From the OP [referenced post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149293) I suggest a change to the group by aggregate function to facilitate functions that do not return scalars.

You may use `Query` and a bit of functional syntax sugar to create a more robust group by aggregate.

```
ClearAll[groupByAggregate]
groupByAggregate[
   grouping_?VectorQ,
   aggregator_?VectorQ,
   columns_,
   columnNames_?VectorQ,
   dat_?(VectorQ[#, AssociationQ] &)
   ] /; Equal @@ Map[Length, {aggregator, columns, columnNames}] :=
 Query[
   GroupBy[# /@ grouping &] /*
    KeyValueMap[
     Association[
       Thread[grouping -> #1],
       Thread[columnNames -> #2]
       ] &],
   Function[{d}, MapIndexed[#1@d[[All, First@#2]] &, aggregator]],
   columns]@dat
```

Then with `a1` as in the reference post

```
groupByAggregate[
  {"L1"},
  {Total, Max},
  {"V1", "V2"},
  {"V1Total", "V2Max"},
  a1
  ] // Dataset
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and even repeated columns and multi-column aggregates

```
groupByAggregate[
  {"L1", "L2"},
  {Total, Total, Max, Total@*Map[#V1 + 2 #V2 &]},
  {"V1", "V2", "V2", KeyTake[{"V1", "V2"}]},
  {"V1Total", "V2Total", "V2Max", "Calc"},
  a1
  ] // Dataset
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now for `Count`

```
groupByAggregate[
  {"L3"},
  {Count[n_ /; n > 1000], Count[n_ /; n < 100]},
  {"V1", "V2"},
  {"V1Count", "V2Count"},
  a1
  ] // Dataset
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

and `Counts`

```
groupByAggregate[
  {"L1", "L2"},
  {Counts, Counts},
  {"V1", "V2"},
  {"V1Count", "V2Count"},
  a1
  ] // Dataset
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps